# Execute event handler in jquery if custom event already triggered

Tags: jquery, events, publish-subscribe

Note: All event pub-sub in my question is via jQuery's on()/trigger()

I have a module (called Header) in my application that triggers a custom event ('Header:init') at some point of time. This event will be triggered exactly once.

Many other modules in the application subscribe to this event. I would like the event handlers in these modules to execute if the 'Header:init' event triggered before the handlers were attached. Else the handlers execute as expected (once 'Header:init' is fired).

I hope I am clear in what I require - the functionality is much like the standard 'ready' event of jQuery - handlers execute as soon as they are attached if DOM is ready, else they execute once DOM is ready.

To reiterate, 'Header:init' is triggered exactly once.

How can I do this? I do't want any variables floating around the application for this. Looking for a clean solution - preferably, just the way ready event works. I checked jQuery site for any event hooks provided by jQuery for this, but everything in centered on browser events like click etc. and none for custom ones.

Appreciate any kind of pointers.

---

Edit: To state clearly the requirement...

Time x : Some module subscribing to the Header:init event has code below and gets executed now...

$( document ).on( 'Header:init', function() {   /* the handler */
    ...
});

Time x + 1 : Suppose the Header module triggered the event now (i.e. a later point of time)

$( document ).trigger( 'Header:init' );

My requirement is the handler should still be executed.

Comment: _"hope I am clear in what I require"_ Not entirely ; at this portion of Question : _"would like the event handlers in these modules to execute if the 'Header:init' event triggered before the handlers were attached"_ ? Before which handlers were attached ?  Can include `js` at Question ?

Comment: _"Time x + 1 : Suppose the Header module triggered the event now (i.e. a later point of time) $( document ).trigger( 'Header:init' ); My requirement is the handler should still be executed."_ Is handler not being called with `js` tried ? Can create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting defining named function for anonymous function at handler , to call named function as handler for different objects

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
// handler for `Header:init` namespace
var handleEvents = function handleEvents(e, msg) {
  $("div").html(msg)
};
// trigger `Header:init` handler `handleEvents` on `document` object
// at `document` ready event 
$(this).on("Header:init", handleEvents)
.trigger("Header:init", [this.nodeName]);
// trigger `handlerEvents` on `"header"` selector , or `document` at `click` event
$("header").on("click", function() {
  // $(document).trigger("Header:init")
  $(this).trigger("Header:init", [this.nodeName])
});
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>click</header>
<div></div>
```